# UITransitionView, UIAlertSheet

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to update an iOS open-source project that has been abandoned in 2008. I've found some references to UITransitionView and UIAlertSheet in the code, but I can't find any documentation on Apple dev center about that. Are they simply deprecated?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They are both internal views used by Apple and not published in the SDK.
>
> It's difficult to say exactly what Apple will or won't do however, adding a view to an undocumented view you retrieve from a superView message is not contentious. What you should not do (or be careful if you do do) is make assumptions about the view you are adding to. Specifically its class but even basic things like the fact that it even exists.
>
> What are you trying to do? There may be a simpler way - like adding your view directly to the app's UIWindow.

[UITransitionView and UILayoutContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781342/uitransitionview-and-uilayoutcontainerview)

[UIAlertSheet Class Reference](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs112/interface_u_i_alert_sheet.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I'm not doing anything, just reading the code to understand it...I also noticed that the GraphicsServices private framework is used, do you know how I can link this framework to a new xcode project? It does not appear in "Existing frameworks" list.

Answer (score 0):

UITransitionView is internal apple framework and not published in SDK..See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781342/uitransitionview-and-uilayoutcontainerview) thread
UIAlertSheet I never heard about..:(