# UIResponder chain produces two extra responders

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiresponder, responder-chain

I'm running Xcode 14.0 beta 4. I have just one ViewController with a `root view` in storyboard. I want to see an entire Responder Chain from UIView to AppDelegate. To do this, I created extensions:

[image]

```
import UIKit

extension AppDelegate {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("APPLICATION")
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
} 
extension UIView {
    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("View")
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
extension UIWindow {
    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Window")
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("CONTROLLER")
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Console gives me out the following sequence:

[image]

**Question**:

Where do these two extra responders come from?

Comment: Include `self` in your print statements to help... e.g. `print("View", self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are `UITransitionView` and `UIDropShadowView`

you can either debug view hierarchy or print self to know it. There is one post on SO about it : [UITransitionView and UILayoutContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/781342/468724), I don't have much knowledge about it nor did I find any apple docs about it. They might be internal APIs

```
extension UIView {
    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("View \(self)")
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also found a way to find out what these two responders are:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private func responderChain(_ responder: UIResponder?) {
        if let responder {
            print(responder)
            responderChain(responder.next)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.responderChain(self)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]